# How to convert one-dimensional array into two-dimensional without memory allocating?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a filled one-dimensional array `double *vals` as a class component with sizes `Nn[0]*Nn[1]`. I need to get 2-dimensional array `**w (w[Nn[1]][Nn[0]])` without allocating new memory for it, e.g. i need to represent `vals` as 2-dimensional array.

Using g++ compiler i can make

```
double (* w)[Nn[0]] = (double (*)[Nn[0]])val;
```

But VS compiler or intel compiler don't allow to use non-constant expression as dimension array.

In general, I can just use element in initial `vals` array converting 2 `int` indices (i,j) of `w[i][j]` element into global index and do not declare `w` at all. But it would be great if it's possible to get 2-dimensional array `w` on initial memory (with compiling with intel compiler too). So is there any way to do it?

Comment: C++ does not allow non-constant expressions as array dimensions, while modern C allows it. So pick one language for the question, instead of two.

Comment: Ok, i deleted C from tags. It's C++ code

Comment: `double *vals` is not an array. It's a pointer.

Comment: What you're describing is the concept of a *view* into another container.  In your case the container is a 1-dimensional array and the view presents it to the caller as a 2-dimensional array.  One such implementation of a view is provided by the [Boost.MultiArray library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html).

Answer (score 1):

If wals is a class, you can implement your access operator to function as if it were 2D array.

```
walsdataType walsclass::operator()(int i, int j){return walsdata[i*N+j]};
```

with walsdata being the class member for storing data and N being the row length. You should do the bound checking as well.

Comment: What operator is that supposed to be?

Comment: That is the access operator. You use it to access the data stored in your member walsdata like this: walsinstance(i,j)

Comment: I don't know any `access operator` in c++. Can you be more specific? Did you mean `operator()(int i, intj)`?

Comment: Yes, since you will be making your own class (I've named it walsclass but you can name it whatever you prefer) and you should implement your access operator, namely operator()(int i, int j). I've also realized that I've made a typo and will correct my answer.